# Iterating over python list only gives each letter

Tags: python, list, cheetah

I have a list..

```
availablethemes = ['cerulean', 'default', 'journal', 'united']
```

And I'm trying to put each item in a dropdown item list

```
<select id="theme" name="theme">
    #for $interface in $availablethemes
         #if $getVar('theme', 'default') == $interface
         <option selected="selected" value="$interface">$interface</option>
         #else
         <option value="$interface">$interface</option>
         #end if
     #end for
 </select>
```

Its part of a cheetah template file and the list is coming for a config file. The issue I'm having is that when its shown its putting each letter individually as if its not a list. Its iterating over each character and not list item. Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: How are you reading the config file? Are you just reading a string `"['cerulean', 'default', 'journal', 'united']"` and expecting it to be treated as a list?

Comment: @Wooble - Yes you right that's the issue. I'm fetching it as a string so its iterating correctly because its a string. Can I fetch it as a string and convert it to a string afterwards or should I be fetching it as a list?

Comment: @Michael In that case it may be easier to just store the items separated by commas in a string, `"cerulean,default,journal,united"` and then when you retrieve it to call `.split(",")` on the retrieved string. If need to go from list to string you can do `",".join(list)`

Comment: @sc0tt - The problem is I'm getting the items from os.listdir which returns a list. However I know the problem now so I'll come up with a solution to work around it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Store it in your config file as [JSON](http://json.org/) and decode it before using.

```
>>> for i in json.loads('["foo", "bar", "baz"]'):
...   print i, repr(i)
... 
foo u'foo'
bar u'bar'
baz u'baz'
```